# Read large number of JSON files at fast speed python by dividing them into patches

Tags: python, json, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am currently reading about 100k JSON files. However, I've a dataset of about 1 million files. I want to find the best possible way to read the files. I've tried multithreading, multiprecessing but I couldn't get it right.

Here are my functions

```
def format_data(data):
    # perform operations
    return data

def load_files_data(files):
    files_data = []
    for file in files:
        filename = file.split(os.sep)[-1].split(".")[0]
        data = load_json_file(file)
        if data is not None:
            files_data.append(data)
    return files_data


def load_json_file(path):
    try:
        with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error reading file at: {path}. Error: {e}")
        return None
```

JSON file content: https://paste.ee/p/CCFeC

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How fast is the current method? Reading a lot of file is slow because random read are much slower. Do you use a HDD or a SSD? If you use a HDD, then the speed is bounded by the IOPS of the storage device and you should not get something faster than 1000 file/s (ie. at least 20 min). SSD are much better for that but the operation should still take at least dozens of seconds on high-end Nvme SSDs. Do you really need UTF-8 decoding? This makes the operation slower. The critical question is: what do you want to do with such loaded files?

Comment: `filename` is not used, is this a mistake or the line is unneeded?

Comment: @JérômeRichard `filename` part is deleted here. I was thinking if there is some way to divide the files into patches and read them and then combine the result? Using multithreading or multiprocessing. I've tried both but none of them improved speed.

Comment: Multithreading only help if you are IO bound and the storage device can benefit from using multiple thread. This is not the case for HDD (actually slower in parallel) and middle-end/low-end SSD does not benefit much from that too. Multiprocessing is mainly useful when the process is compute-bound or the GIL is an issue. The thing is it introduce a big overhead if loaded json files contains a lot of object due to inter-process communication. Thus, this is very dependent of your json files. Providing an example of loaded file can help to reproduce this. Providing more infos too.

Comment: In your case, merging the files in a big one should help a lot assuming you could change the way input files are produced.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Added JSON file format to question

Comment: Ok. The utf-8 encoding make sense. Can you put this in a text rather than an image (according to [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))? By the way, do you need all the information in the json file or just a part?

Comment: I need all information. I tried to copy content but it marked it as spam. I've added a past.ee link. You can see the content there.
I also perform some formatting on the data loaded from JSON file. If that can be somehow parallalized then it will really speed up the process.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that using multiprocessing is faster on systems with a high-end Nvme SSD and/or when the files are cached by the operating system. This is because the many system calls generated by this processing are pretty expensive and the loaded json files are relatively small resulting in a reasonable inter-process communication overhead.

Here is an example of code using multiprocessing:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import json
from time import time

def load_json_file(path):
    try:
        with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error reading file at: {path}. Error: {e}")
        return None

def load_files_data(files):
    with Pool() as pool:
        files_data = [data for data in pool.map(load_json_file, files) if data is not None]
        return files_data
```

This code is about 3 times faster on my machine with the example json file you provided. Note that this is better if you can compute the json files directly in parallel so to make the operation more compute-bound.

Note that if you use an HDD or a low-end SSD, and files are not cached by the operating system, then the operation will be bounded by the number of IOPS of the storage device and there is nothing to do except **merging the json files to a big archive file**. This strategy should result in a much faster loading time on most system (even when files are cached in memory by the operating system).